# how to change date format in elasticseearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to change the date format of one of the field in elasticsearch (v2.3). At present it has field:value in the format as shown below:

```
"lastChange" : "2019-07-05 11:35:16"
```

Now I want to add UTC in the time format so that it looks like

```
"lastChange" : "2019-07-05 11:35:16 UTC"
```

I've tried query `curl -u user:passwd -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/proc/task/_update_by_query' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' {"script":{"inline":"ctx._source.lastChange=2018-01-01"},"query":{"exists":{"field":"jSrcIp"}}}'` but this is failing with following error

```
{"took":58,"timed_out":false,"total":3,"updated":0,"batches":1,"version_conflicts":0,"noops":0,"retries":0,"failures":[{"index":"proc_v1","type":"tasks","id":"10","cause":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse [lastChange]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Invalid format: \"2016\" is too short"}},"status":400},{"index":"proc_v1","type":"tasks","id":"11","cause":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse [lastChange]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Invalid format: \"2016\" is too short"}},"status":400},{"index":"proc_v1","type":"tasks","id":"12","cause":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse [lastChange]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Invalid format: \"2016\" is too short"}},"status":400}]}
```

Also, I am not sure why it says

> "2016 is too short"

in the error.

But if I try to change another field similarly, it worked. I tried another query `curl -u user:passwd -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/proc/tasks/_update_by_query' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' {"script":{"inline":"ctx._source.fileSize=2000"},"query":{"exists":{"field":"jSrcIp"}}}'` and all the records has new fileSize field with value 2000.

Comment: This might help you out:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/mapping-date-format.html

Comment: @NicolaeMaties, Thanks for the link. is it possible for you to help me with the query where I can change the timezone. e.g. if currently DB has time in PST, it gets converted to UTC?